# How to to add a decimal and zero and decimal to a numbers input in jQuery

Tags: jquery, input

I apologise if this has been answered, though I cannot find the solution or the correct way to ask my question via Google or on the search here.

**Problem**

Currently my *buttons* from `0.0` to `0.0000` work and successfully copy the value from the button to the input field.

Say if I entered `2` in the input field and then press the decimal 
 `.` button I've created (first button) it'll remove my number I typed `2` and want the decimal after.

Then if I try and press `0.` I get the following error in console:

```
jquery.min.js:4 The specified value "0." is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="cplpc-btc-dotz" value=".">.</button>
<button id="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.">0.</button>
<button id="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.0">0.0</button>
<button id="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.00">0.00</button>
<button id="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.000">0.000</button>
<button id="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.0000">0.0000</button>    `
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#btc-invest-dots button#cplpc-btc-dotz').on( 'click', function(e){
    var btcinvst = $(this).val();
    cplpcbtc = $('input#cplpcbtc');
    cplpcbtc.val(btcinvst);
    cplpcbtc.focus();
});
```

I did try adding a backspace and change the value of `0.` to `0.0` using the following code which failed with:

```
$('#btc-invest-dots button#cplpc-btc-dotf').on( 'click', function(e){
    var btcinvst = $(this).val();
    cplpcbtc = $('input#cplpcbtc');
    cplpcbtc.focus();
    var bk = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 49 });
    $("input#cplpcbtc").trigger( bk );
    cplpcbtc.val(btcinvst).focus().trigger( bk );
});
```

*This didn't work haha.*

Perhaps I could trigger a `keypress` once the `button` is pressed? Though I don't think this is the best option and wouldn't be sure how to go about that.

**EDIT/UPDATE**
To help make it clearer:
If I press 0.0 it'll add 0.0 which is what I want.. so then I can add additional numbers after that if I choose. However, if I hit 0. it won't add 0. so I can't then adding numbers after 0. for example 0.144
The same goes for adding a period/decimal when I want to add one. Say I type 22 I want to be able to hit the period button and it'll add a decimal 22. and then I can add more numbers if I want: 22.44 for example.

Any advise or opinions are welcome! Thanks :-)

You can see my attempt here: [Pastebin](https://jsfiddle.net/pkeLky7g/10/)

Comment: So i cant  understand  what you need exactly?  You want to type a number to your input and then if you press your button (#cplpc-btc-dotz) , this value will add to you input ?For example ,  you type 2 in your input, and click button 0.0 , the final result will be 20.0 ? Something like that?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want it so if I have the input focused and type 2 and then press the dot button it'll now be 2. and I also want it so if I press 0. it'll add 0. to the input and then I can type numbers after 0. If you press any of the other buttons you will see what I mean. As for example if I press 0.0 then it'll add 0.0 then I can start adding numbers after that 0.01234 etc. I want the same with 0. though it doesn't work like the others? I want to add . after I have typed numbers 22. for example. Hopefully this makes sense haha?

Comment: I don't think this is gonna work in the way you think it in a number input with demical numbers  .I made a fiddle for you to have a start point, good luck :  https://jsfiddle.net/pkeLky7g/65/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not allowed to set values like `o.` inside `<input type="number">`. Allowing user to set values ending with dot might require additional validation, but if you hardly need this, here is possible solution.

You can use `<input type="text">` instead and add some additional handlers to make it act like `<input type="number">`.

```
$("input.number").on("keypress", function(e) {
  if (($(this).val().substring(0, $(this)[0].selectionStart) + e.originalEvent.key + $(this).val().substring($(this)[0].selectionEnd)).match( /^(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]*)?$/ ) == null) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
$("input.number").on("paste", function(e) {
  if (($(this).val().substring(0, $(this)[0].selectionStart) + e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text") + $(this).val().substring($(this)[0].selectionEnd)).match( /^(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]*)?$/ ) == null) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

This will handle every input both by printing and pasting. `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties are used to determine if current text is selected. If not, they are both equal to current cursor position. The regular expression will allow all the same, what is allowed for `<input type="number">` plus values ending with dot. In fact, on every change of your input you build future value, check it with regex and prevent if it doesn't match.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

1. Here is full working code:

HTML

```
<div id="btc-invest-dots">
  <button class="cplpc-btc-dotf" value=".">.</button>
  <button class="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.0">0.</button>
  <button class="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.0">0.0</button>
  <button class="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.00">0.00</button>
  <button class="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.000">0.000</button>
  <button class="cplpc-btc-dotz" value="0.0000">0.0000</button>
</div>
<div id="btc-invest-input-cont">
  <input type="text" class="number" id="cplpcbtc">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $("input.number").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (($(this).val().substring(0, $(this)[0].selectionStart) + e.originalEvent.key + $(this).val().substring($(this)[0].selectionEnd)).match( /^(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]*)?$/ ) == null) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  $("input.number").on("paste", function(e) {
    if (($(this).val().substring(0, $(this)[0].selectionStart) + e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text") + $(this).val().substring($(this)[0].selectionEnd)).match( /^(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]*)?$/ ) == null) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  $('#btc-invest-dots button.cplpc-btc-dotz').on( 'click', function(e) {
    $('input#cplpcbtc').val($(this).text()).focus();
  });
  $('#btc-invest-dots button.cplpc-btc-dotf').on( 'click', function(e) {
    if (($("input.number").val() + ".").match( /^(0|([1-9][0-9]*))(\.[0-9]*)?$/ ) != null) {
      $("input.number").val($("input.number").val() + ".").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

2. Use `.text()` for buttons, not `val()`. Value `0.` is automatically converted to `0.0`.
3. **Never use duplicate IDs.** This may cause a lot of headache in future.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted and I changed the type to TEL so I can still get a number area on mobiles instead of qwerty keyboard :-)